# What is the correct XPath expression for element with attributes?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML document, fragment below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>myapp.applications</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

I want to select the value of `groupId` with something similar to

```
xml.xpath("//project/parent/groupId").text
```

This doesn't work as a result of all of the attributes. I think.

If change document to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>myapp.applications</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

it does work.

So it seems XPath expression is not valid for project element with attributes.

What is the correct XPath expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `xmlns` "attributes" are not attributes, they're **namespace** definitions. Element `//project` means "project in the empty namespace", but your `project` is in a non-empty namespace. You need to register the namespace with a prefix (the syntax depends on the language you're using) and then use

```
//p:project/p:parent/p:groupId
```

Comment: I am using Nokogiri Rubygem. With this answer I was able to find solution as simple as using method for this `remove_namespaces`

Answer (score 1):

1 you can use at root:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

2 do that also

```
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

3 then

```
String expression="//project/parent/groupId";

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if (prefix == null) throw new NullPointerException("Null prefix");
        return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
    }
    public String getPrefix(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
};
xpath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression) ; 

NodeList nodes  = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

it works